# Variable access throughout the program

Tags: c++, variables

i have created following

- `class xyz`
- `void main()` - to calculate some value (C)
- `int main()` - to create object of class xyz and call main()

Now i want to return that value (C) from this function

any solutions??

```
class xyz
{ public: void main()
};
void xyz::main()
{
    int a =1;
    int b=2;
    int c=a+b;
}
int main()
{ 
    xyz o;
    o.main();
    return c;
}
```

I know span of c is only in void main() how can i return the value of c from int main()?

Comment: Please add some more detail. Do you really have two `main` functions? Which function do you want to return a value from? Why doesn't it have a return type of `xyz`? Why can't you simply `return value;`?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking. I think the basic question is that you have class xyz to calculate something, and you don't know how to use that class from main and return the value you're calculating. That the basic question?

Comment: @MikeSeymour class is just to define public functions nothing more than that....void main () does all the calculations..lets say it give me a final result (X integer type)...now int main() is used to create the object of the class and calling void main() now i want to return that X value(calculated in void main) from int main()

Comment: The question is not clear... I tried answering but I am not sure I understand what you want. Please add real code to the question.

Comment: @anatolyg i have added the sample code....

Comment: @anatolyg i am having that constraint to keep it as void main()....

Answer (score 2):

The value is going to go from `xyz::main` into `main`, and then from `main` to the operating system. This is the concept of "return values": a function (method) returns a value to its caller.

To make it work, declare a proper return type instead of `void`:

```
int xyz::main() // here
{
    ...
}
```

At the end of the method, return the value:

```
int xyz::main()
{
    ...
    return c; // here
}
```

In the `main` function, receive the returned value:

```
int main()
{ 
    xyz o;
    int c1 = o.main(); // here
    return c1;
}
```

Comment: pretty much the answer to the question